# Gizmo not always visible

Tags: gizmo

I want to have the gizmo shown when I zoom in (on purple square) on the object further down, in this case. Sometimes you need to be up close when you rotate for precision. I get that the gizmo follows the orange dot here and that I could set the orange dot to the 3D cursor after I set the 3D cursor to the "rope handles" foot, but what happens then is the object won't rotate even in any axis :O

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to:

1. Select your object and switch to "edit mode".
2. Select the bottom face of your object
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select "Cursor to selected".
4. Switch back to "object mode".
5. In the upper panel set *Transform pivot point* to *Cursor* and *Transform orientation* to *Local*.

You should now see the gizmo at the bottom of your object and aligned with its orientation.